# Search with Javascript a JSON, using form parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, search

I'm making a webapp that will search cards based on parameters given.

The problem lies on the fact that the cards have different types. For instance one card may have something like `"income": 4`, while another behaves completely different and has an attribute `"cost" : 5`. All i meant is that my JSON has 5 types of different objects, that although they share many similarities, they have certain distinctions.

So let's  say that my user searches for a card based on the Title. All of them has this attribute, so it's fairly easy to make an condition like this.

```
if ((item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(cardParams.searchTitle.toLowerCase())  > -1) && (cardParams.searchTitle != null ) && (cardParams
        .searchTitle.length > 0)){
```

But what if my user wants to search the text in the body too? All of them the have one too, so this leads to another condition with starts making things awkward.

Furthermore, let's way that my user triggers my worst case scenario and asks for two attributes that no card has them at the same time along with the ones above. One would say that i should work on my form to make them mutually exclusive, but programmatically this is beyond me.

What i've decided to go for is to search for each attribute seperately and save the results all into an array. If i have as many duplicates of an card as many valid attributes (not null or empty), then i would keep them.

This is really really clumsy and not optimal. I'm sure there are very simple solutions that i can't think of.

How can i proceed such a problem? Is creating tons of conditions the only way to go? What should i do?

Edit: Thanks for the downvotes. It's like i ask for fun.

Comment: You just want to have an answer to easily search all attributes (or rather properties) of the `item` object?

Comment: "search json"? as in `somejsontext.indexof()`. Or search through some JS datastructure which used to be a json string?

Comment: @MarcB It's in JSON format, i got it from an API. Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: json is just text. and not something you want to search as a string. you normally DECODE It into a native structure. consider json the equivalent of a gift-wrapped present. you don't deal with the giftwrap, you unwrap the present and work the present itself.

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, but sometimes i might have 2,3 or 6 attributes to search against. It's not static.

Comment: if you will to use angular, try to use $filter. Sample: $filter('filter')(yourJsonList, { age: 20, color: 'red'}) . It will to return a filtered list with your defined filters.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I'm using a custom filter. In anyway forget this really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search across an object inside javascript, you can just loop over the properties, and access those for which the `object.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` returns true

As an example, you see here a bunch of cards, with different properties, the search will however iterate over all of the properties of each card and will select a card that matches and then search for the next matching card.

At the end it will either show the results, or simply say there are no results found ;)

```js
var cards = [{
  title: 'Card 1',
  prop1: 'Test of card1',
  description: 'Description of card1',
  customCard1: 'Custom property'
}, {
  title: 'Card 2',
  description: 'Description of card2',
  customCard2: 'Custom property card2'
}];

function searchCards() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('searchBox').value.toLowerCase(),
    i, len, card, prop, matches = [],
    val;

  for (i = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++) {
    card = cards[i];
    for (prop in card) {
      if (card.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        val = card[prop];
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined' && val.toLowerCase && val.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt) >= 0) {
          // this card matches
          matches.push(card);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  showMatches(matches);
}

function showMatches(matches) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('result'),
    i, len, content = '';
  if (typeof matches === 'undefined' || !matches.length) {
    elem.innerHTML = '<i>No results found</i>';
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++) {
    content += '<div><b>title:</b>' + matches[i].title + '</div>';
  }
  elem.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchBox" />
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:searchCards()">Search</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Update based on the comments**

If you have multiple input fields, you could give them an extra class to recognise them, and then let jQuery return you all the matching elements based on your selector (in my case, .search), and get the values that were given by the user, then you can simply check if your card has a defined value for it, and if this defined value is really part of the card itself

I reused some code from the first snippet, didn't want to spend to much extra time on it ;)

```js
var cards = [{
  title: 'Card 1',
  prop1: 'Test of card1',
  description: 'Description of card1',
  customCard1: 'Custom property'
}, {
  title: 'Card 2',
  description: 'Description of card2',
  customCard2: 'Custom property card2'
}];


function getSearchParameters() {
  var properties = [];
  $('.search').each(function() {
    if (this.value) {
      properties.push(this.value);
    }
  });
  return properties;
}

function search() {
  var properties = getSearchParameters(), i, len, card, matches = [], p, plen, prop, match;
  for (i = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++) {
    card = cards[i];
    match = true;
    for (p = 0, plen = properties.length; p < plen; p++) {
      prop = properties[p];
      if (typeof card[prop] === 'undefined' || !card.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        // didn't find a property, this doesn't match
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
      matches.push(card);
    }
  }
  showMatches(matches);
}


function showMatches(matches) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('result'),
    i, len, content = '';
  if (typeof matches === 'undefined' || !matches.length) {
    elem.innerHTML = '<i>No results found</i>';
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++) {
    content += '<div><b>title:</b>' + matches[i].title + '</div>';
  }
  elem.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<input type="text" class="search" />
<button type="button" onclick="search()">Search for matching properties</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for, but i will accept it since you took the time.

Comment: @user3675818 That's nice but it doesn't help anybody else in the future. Can you explain what you are missing in the answer? From your question, it's kinda hazy to understand what exactly you want to do. Any chance you could put in more code or a better description (edit your question?)

Comment: I have 10 inputs. My user may use 1, 2 or all of them. I want to get the inputs and search against a json file, to see which object contains the values my user submitted.

Comment: and those inputs are linked to properties, or they are just general input fields (and should all inputs matches, or is one input enough to return a match)

Comment: They are linked to the properties. I want to have complete match. My main problem is that as i said i have a worst case scenario where i can be given two properties that a card does not have at the same time. Ignoring this for the time being, i want to recognize which properties are passed so to only search the appropriate fields.

Comment: @user3675818 I hope I understood you better this time, I updated my answer with a second snippet

Comment: I merely wanted what you did in the first one, but with many inputs. For example i would write "test of" and "custom" and would get card 1. Not only one field. Thanks though.